# How can I make Unix directory read-only for myself?

Tags: ssh, unix, file-permissions

I've been given a path to some files on a unix server I'm working on through ssh. I don't want to waste space by creating a duplicate in my home area so I've linked the folder through `ln -s`. However I don't want to risk making any changes to the data within the folder.

I am not the owner of the file and I do not have root access. How would I go about setting the files to read-only for myself?

Comment: `sshfs` mounted locally with `-o ro`? I have no experience with it, that's why it's a comment.

Comment: Maybe, but I'd like to leverage the compute resources on the server too.

Comment: [`bindfs`](http://bindfs.org/) then, if it's available. Or ask root to `mount --bind -r` it for you.

Comment: Another fuse-based solution: `rofs`. It's in Debian repositories; I don't know about other OS-es.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. Since you are not the owner of the file (or root), you cannot change the permissions or change the file attributes. Also, since you're not root, you cannot install 3rd party software that would allow this (like `bindfs` that Kamil suggested in the comments).

You can ask the owner to change your specific permissions using extended file attributes (depending on your Unix flavour and filesystem used).

Comment: So you are saying there's no way for me to limit my own write access to a file without being the owner or root?

Comment: Yes, well at least not with the default tool set that is available on Unix systems.